# How to change only certain values in a column with mapping? - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change specific values in my `chicken` column based on my `chunkiness` column. My `chicken` column contains `bob`, `all`, `berries`, `moss`.

```
mapping_dict = {0.0: "small", 1.0: "meh", 2.0: "big", 3.0: "chunky!"}
im_df["chicken"] = im_df.chunkiness.map(mapping_dict)
```

problem here, is that anything with an empty `chunkiness` (valid btw) it just sets the `chicken` value to `None`.

How can I have it so it doesn't change anything that does not have an entry in the `chunkiness` column i.e. `NaN`?

Comment: `im_df["chicken"] = im_df.chunkiness.map(mapping_dict).fillna(im_df["chicken"], inplace=False)` - I haven't tested this, but it should work.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks Larry :), provide that as the answer so i can upvote it and accept

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to run your code due to missing data, but perhaps adding `na_action='ignore'` to the `map` method might work:

```py
mapping_dict = {0.0: "small", 1.0: "meh", 2.0: "big", 3.0: "chunky!"}
im_df["chicken"] = im_df.chunkiness.map(mapping_dict, na_action='ignore')
```

Comment: I don't think that does, because it will just copy across the NaN regardless.